# Can a laser display numbers like an LCD 7 segment display?

Tags: 7segmentdisplay, laser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to convert a 7 segment display to be displayed by a laser beam?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/56497/is-there-a-way-to-convert-a-7-segment-display-to-be-displayed-by-a-laser-beam)

I am a 12 year old child with a growing interest in electronics. I want to have a laser project numbers like a 7 segment display. Is there a way to hook a 7 segment display up to a laser to have the laser display the numbers onto a flat surface?

The design needs to be as compact as possible. Do you know if maybe there is an electronic converter or way that can be used to hook it up in place of the 7 segment display? Like this:

Binary for the 7 segment display -> ??Mystery part described above??? -> Laser display module.

I just started electronics a few days ago, I've got some grasp on the basic stuff, but I could really use some help here. I have a very limited amount of resources available and needed to ask people who know what they're doing.

Comment: There are small alarm clocks that project the time onto the ceiling. However these usually employ a bright LED, an LCD panel, and a lens to focus. Therefore, are you certain you need a laser? Example: http://www.amazon.com/Oregon-Scientific-Rm313pa-Exactset-Projection/dp/B004OV57F4

Comment: I am new to electronics, but I am thinking of designing a laser display pocket watch, I am aware that there has been a laser watch created that displays time using lasers projected, so I wanted to base it off that. Do you think a laser is necessary or should I use LEDs If I want such a display? Thank you for being so understanding @JYelton!

Comment: Something that fits in the pocket is going to be limited in size, and most importantly, in available power. A simple 5mW laser pointer (great for entertaining cats) is cheap, takes 3 button cells, and can fit on a keychain. Modifying it to display useful information will require some ingenuity. For something like that, I wouldn't try using traditional laser projection techniques. You might try the same approach as in the alarm clocks. The question is how far do you expect to project the time? A pocket laser or LED system will probably only get you a few meters, at most.

Comment: Posting exactly the same question again is not the way to get people to answer your question. Next time, edit your old question, and when you do so, it will be proposed for re-opening.

Comment: You might buy [this time projector device on eBay for $2.50](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Red-LED-Laser-Light-Time-Digital-Projection-Projector-Clock-Key-ring-Gift-Gadget-/330747739085) and figure out how it works.  It appears to use an LED and LCD even though it advertises "laser."

Comment: I want it to project at most 6 inches away from the pocket watch.

Comment: Thanks JYelton, The LED keychain is actually pretty close to what I wanted, Do you know If something like it could be easily modified to only display the letters in light and not the rectangular background color. Thank you for being so helpful, This now seems achievable for someone like me.

Comment: If the pocket keychain is close range, could something similar be used (or to modify the keychain) to  make it work up to 3 or 4 feet away?

Comment: @PhilFrost, Please excuse me for that, I'm new to the site and I thought since my original question was not a question that the chances of It being reopened were slim, so I edited the question, realized it would take a while to reopen, then posted a new question, am i allowed do delete questions off the site? I would like to erase the old question.

Comment: I'm not *that* familiar with using small LCD panels to project light through. It should be possible to inverse the panel such that the liquid crystal allows digit segments to be projected and block light otherwise. That might be a good new question for you to ask; one that's specific to LCD panels and projecting light through them. Unfortunately I'm not an expert on that.

Comment: I found a way to invert the LCD screen! If I remove the screen from the casing and then remove the polarized film and flip it, It's supposed to invert the screen.

Answer (score 3):

Laser displays, at least for entertainment, generally involve the following components:

- Laser: This can be any of several types. If you want a full-color display, often two or more lasers are employed with combining optics to achieve a white light. HeNe produce red, Argon produce blue-green, etc. The size of the display intended determines the size and power of laser needed. I've seen small displays that use diode lasers, and large displays that use 10W lasers that require exciters and water cooling.
- Scanner pair: A scanner pair is essentially a pair of servo motors with first-surface mirrors mounted to them. One acts as a bounce mirror to control the X-axis while the other controls the Y-axis. The scanner pair "aims" the beam at the desired point on the display surface.
- Blanking: You will need a way to blank the output. Imagine a "C" shape, if you draw such an arc from top to bottom, if you do not blank the output while traveling from the stop point back to the start point, you will wind up with a backward "D". Blanking is therefore done to cause the light output to stop while positioning the scanner pair during periods of travel that do not involve drawing. This can be done with a PCAOM or, with some lasers, actually switching them off. High-power lasers cannot be switched at a high frequency, but diode lasers can.
- Color selection: A PCAOM (Poly-chromatic Acoustic Optic Modulator) is essentially a crystal that can deform its shape based on an input radio frequency. Some can act as a blanking device, to bend light such that it is not aimed at the scanner pair. A PCAOM takes an input of white light, and allows the output of a specific color. It is essentially a variable prism.
- Controller: A computer or microcontroller is required to coordinate all of the above. You need a way to orchestrate the motion of the scanner, the color or blanking of the beam, and generally at a high frequency. The dimensions and viewing distance of the display surface govern these requirements.

There are other ways to use lasers to project images, but this is the way I am familiar with. If you research these topics, I think you will find that you can focus your questions more specifically.

Comment: For more information: http://www.laserfx.com/Works/Works3.html

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to apologise for asking any question at all, that's what the site is here for :-)

Okay, about the laser display - it would be possible to have a laser project numbers onto a flat surface (has been done as I'm sure you know) but not by connecting a laser to an ordinary 7 segment display, no. 
I think what you mean is the 7-segment driver rather than the display, which is just a bunch of LEDs arranged suitably.

The way to do it would be to use something like a piezo controlled mirror arrangement with the laser (moves the mirrors slightly to reflect and move the laser point) and scan the display like an old CRT (Cathode Ray Tube) TV does, turning on the laser at the appropriate times. I think there are a couple of laser projection modules out there that do something like this to project video onto any flat surface.

The above would be a pretty difficult project for an experienced person, and I'm not aware of any dedicated chips that would do the job of driving the laser and whatever moves it (i.e. anything like your mystery part) Microcontroller knowledge and experience with various types of digital/analogue circuitry would be necessary - although the actual concept of building a picture gradually is not so difficult, the implementation is.

You might want to check out [POV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_of_vision) projects ([example](http://www.ladyada.net/make/minipov3/index.html), [example 2](http://www.instructables.com/id/SpokePOV%3a-LED-Bike-Wheel-Images/)) which are a bit similar but much easier to make, plus there are kits and plenty of info available out here.

Comment: Do you think this is doable for an inexperienced person like me if they have the right parts? @OliGlaser

Comment: @A.I. - I don't want to discourage you, but I'm afraid not, no - as I mentioned, it's quite a job for a professional EE. As for the POV displays, I think they are doable. This is a huge and complex subject, you (unfortunately) have to start with the simple stuff and work through the theory/practice and make plenty of mistakes along the way.

Comment: Also, I think using some LEDs and a lens to project as @JYeltons suggests in the comments would certainly be a far easier project, and within the scope of a beginner.

Comment: Thank you for your expert advice! This site is really helpful and you folks are really friendly!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to project an image with a laser is to use a hologram. There are several commercial "virtual keyboards" based on this concept, such as [this one from Brookstone](http://www.brookstone.com/laser-projection-virtual-keyboard). Another example is the spinning hologram in a supermarket UPC scanner that sweeps a laser beam in a complex pattern to pick up the bar code at any angle.

However, each such hologram is static; to project a different image requires a different hologram. To simulate a 7-segment display would require a separate hologram for each segment, or a series of holograms that contain all 7 segments for all of the digits or characters you want to display. These holograms could be mounted on a spinning disk, and the laser could be strobed to select the correct images.