# Laser controller project

Tags: motor, voltage-regulator, raspberry-pi, laser

The context is that I want to build a tunnel laser effect, that modulates the angle of the cone according to a sine wave. The purpose being, to create a cool Borg weapon effect for a Star Trek Borg cube model.

Constraints are size (8 inch cube) and cost (just a model, so not looking for a lot).

The tunnel laser seems easy, angled mirror on a motor deflecting the laser. The trouble is in modulating the angle. One method I've thought of is to modulate the motor speed, to increase/decrease the centrifugal force, which will push the mirror into a more flat shape (with some sort of spring tension resisting it) as it increases.

My question is generally what's the easiest way of modulating a voltage/motor according to a sine wave?

I have thought of maybe getting a Raspberry Pi with controller board for this, but I don't know much about the available controllers.

I wonder if perhaps there exists some sort of X-Y controller motor package for manually setting the laser direction at high speed? Which is what I believe the high end laser effects use.

Comment: You may find [a previous answer of mine](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/56501/2028) useful for your laser project.

Comment: High-end projects use galvanometers, but they're fairly big and fairly expensive.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider a small servo to move your laser right and left. Move it from the center of the angled spinning reflector to the edge. Draw out some angles and see what it looks like.